# Trying to debug jquery's `.hover` event

Tags: jquery, hover

I am working with 3 tabs, and the hover event doesn't seem to be kicking in. I have some PHP that determines whether we're in a section where we should use a different image source, hence the PHP. The PHP is spitting out the right SRC as far as I can see.

The code:

```
$("#tab1").hover(
  ("#tab1").attr("src","img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab1.png"),
  ("#tab1").attr("src","PHP_SRC1"));

$("#tab2").hover(
  ("#tab2").attr("src","img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab2.png"),
  ("#tab2").attr("src","PHP_SRC2"));

$("#tab3").hover(
  ("#tab3").attr("src","img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab3.png"),
  ("#tab3").attr("src","PHP_SRC3"));
```

Where `PHP_SRC(num)` is a PHP open and close tag surrounding echo `$tab_image_(num)`.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to bind the "hover" event? Cause in that case you need to pass 2 function to the $.hover function???

Comment: I know its been edited now, but please use the "code" wrapping when placing code in your posts in the future its the button that looks like `{ }` just write your code out, and then highlight it then hit that button.

Comment: I'd go with `delegate()` instead of `bind()` as bind can be dangerous if not used properly. And It can be cumbersome as well. That said try for the sake of trying to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` all though attr is a nice function, some things give it problems sometimes. Also. Another alternative could be to have both images loaded up one with a property of display none sitting next to the one you want to swap out. And you could just do `show()`/`hide()` respectively.

Comment: You need to read the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/hover - the `hover()` method accepts two functions. You have two statements.

Comment: I have a lot of other show-hide things going on throughout the site.

I will just make these statements into functions as implied by ahren and charly.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is that you are missing the `$` at the beginning of your `mouseover, mouseout` functions. Try adding them in:

```
$("#tab1").hover(
    $("#tab1").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab1.png"),
    $("#tab1").attr("src", "PHP_SRC1")
);
$("#tab2").hover(
    $("#tab2").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab2.png"),
    $("#tab2").attr("src", "PHP_SRC2")
);
$("#tab3").hover(
    $("#tab3").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab3.png"),
    $("#tab3").attr("src", "PHP_SRC3")
);
```

If that doesn't work, try wrapping them in anonymous functions:

```
$("#tab1").hover(
    function () {$("#tab1").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab1.png");},
    function () {$("#tab1").attr("src", "PHP_SRC1");}
);
$("#tab2").hover(
    function () {$("#tab2").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab2.png");},
    function () {$("#tab2").attr("src", "PHP_SRC2");}
);
$("#tab3").hover(
    function () {$("#tab3").attr("src", "img/home_menu_images/png/home_mainmenu_hover_tab3.png");},
    function () {$("#tab3").attr("src", "PHP_SRC3");}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like jquery tabs from my own point of view... there is a simpler way to make tabs... you add html anchors combined with ul li tags and then you add jquery click events on them... in the click event you make a $post or a $get and then you render what you whant in a div container... this is way more simpler than using these tabs controls...

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a onclick="function1()" class="active">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="function2()">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
</div>

<script>
  function function1() {
     $('#content').html('Loading...');
        $.get("/yourdomain/someurl1", { }, function(data) {            
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
  }

  function function2() {
     $('#content').html('Loading...');
        $.post("/yourdomain/someurl2", { id: 1}, function(data) {            
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
  }
</script>
```

It's up to you